# Printing all characters in a string in C

Tags: c

I have a very simple program to print the chars in a string but for some reason it is not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void * print_chars(char *process_string) {
    int i;
    int string_len;

    string_len = strlen(process_string);

    printf("String is %s, and its length is %d", process_string, string_len);

    for(i = 0; i < string_len; i++) {
        printf(process_string[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    char *process_string;

    process_string = "This is the parent process.";

    print_chars(process_string);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Netbeans, I get the following:

```
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 98ms)
```

If I remove the line

```
printf(process_string[i]);
```

the program runs but nothing prints out to the console (obviously).

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: By putting that C++ tag there, you should be accepting when someone tells you to just use `std::string` and `std::string::length`.

Comment: Are you paying attention to the warnings you get when you try to compile?

Comment: Why is your `print_chars` function returning a `void *`?? And to print the string, use `printf( "%s", process_string );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

One is that you're not seeing any output from the `printf("String is %s, and its length is %d", ...)`. This is because standard output is line buffered by default, and you are not including a newline, so it never actually decides that there's a line ready to print. If you change the format string to add a `\n`, you will see the output from this command.

The second is that you are passing a `char` into the first argument of `printf()`, where it expects a `char *`. This causes it to crash, as it tries to interpret that character as a pointer. You want to pass something like `printf(process_string)` instead. However, it's generally a bad idea to pass a variable string directly into the first argument of `printf()`; instead, you should pass a format string that includes `%s`, and pass the string in as the corresponding argument: `printf("%s\n", process_string)`. Or, if you want to print it character by character, `printf("%c", process_string[i])`, followed by a `printf("\n")` to flush the buffer and actually see the output. Or if you're doing it character by character, `putchar(process_string[i])` will be simpler than `printf()`.

Answer (score 10):

You need a format in the line

```
printf(process_string[i]);
```

i.e.

```
printf("%c", process_string[i]);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm amazed the posted code actually compiled. But maybe the posted code isn't correct either.

Comment: So am I - wish people read the manual page and understand it.

Comment: That's correct solution, but you've failed to explain why the old code was wrong: the computer is trying to interpret the characters as memory addresses, and reading from an address that does not exist causes a program crash.

Comment: Yes I did - I mentioned that you need a format in the line in question. I am pretty sure that the person can look up the library function. He did ask what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` expects, as first parameter, a *pointer to char*. What you are passing is a *char*, not a pointer to one.

Anyway, `printf()` is not the function to use here. Try `putc()`...